# Preserving permissions when copying tables in Postgres/Greenplum

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I'm trying to copy tables in Postgres and Greenplum, preserving the user privileges:

```
GRANT ALL ON old_table TO user_group;
CREATE TABLE new_table (LIKE old_table);
```

When "new_table" is created, it does not have the same user privileges.  I assumed that this would be granted on the new table by default on creation.  From what I can gather there is no easy way to copy permissions from one table to another, apart from updating "pg_class".  This is not an option for me, as the user creating the table may not necessarily have access to to system catalog.

Does anybody know of any other method?  I'm hoping that there's something simple that I'm missing.

Comment: In Postgres you can use `alter default privileges`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html  But  I have no idea if Greenplum supports that

Comment: You don't have an option to copy table access privileges in Greenplum, and Greenplum does not allow direct pg_class updates. You have to manually execute all grants on it, and you can use pg_dump to dump the grants. Also Greenplum does not support default privileges yet as it is based on Postgres 8.2 (now rebasing to 8.4)